# JSONStream handle one data with different parser

Tags: node.js, jsonstream

I'm using JSONStream to parse the data from server, the data can either be like {"error": "SomeError"} or {"articles":[{"id": 123}]};

My code goes like

```
var request = require('request');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var articleIDParser = JSONStream.parse(['articles', true, 'id']);
var errorParser = JSONStream.parse(['error']);

request({url: 'http://XXX/articles.json'})
    .pipe(articleIDParser).pipe(errorParser);

errorParser.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

articleIDParser.on('data', someFuncHere);
```

But unlucky, the second parser does not work even when the server returns error.

Am I wrong at pipe function or JSONStream?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in Node.js [Stream documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback).

The callback function of the 'end' event doesn't have a data parameter. Listen for the 'data' event instead. In case of piping listen for the [pipe](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe%20%22Streams%20-%20Node.js) event on the destination.

```
var request, JSONStream, articleIDParser, errorParser;
request = require('request');
JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
articleIDParser = JSONStream.parse(['articles', true, 'id']);
errorParser = JSONStream.parse(['error']);

articleIDParser.on('pipe', function (src) {
    // some code
});
errorParser.on('pipe', function (src) {
    // some code
});
request({url: 'http://XXX/articles.json'}).pipe(articleIDParser).pipe(errorParser);
```

**Note:** JSONStream.getParserStream is less ambiguous, one might think you're already parsing while you're just getting the parser/writable stream. If you still have issues please give more information (code) about JSONStream. The Stream module is still marked as unstable by the way.

Comment: Thanks Kem, it's my mistake, I correct the code but problem still exists. Seems the second parser is ignored

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use the following way to solved the problem:

```
var request({url: 'http://XXX/articles.json'})
dest.pipe(articleIDParser)
dest.pipe(errorParser);
```